# Swipe left-right and zooming for imageview

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, swipe

I want to apply pinch zoom in, zoom out and swiping left, right on imageview but both feature not working properly either pinch zooming works or swiping. I want to be work both functionality pinch zooming and swiping.

Is there any way which will be helpful for both? Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library that provides all these features very easily.

Checkout this library [here](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)

Edit:

Basically you just need to use `com.ortiz.touchview.TouchImageView` instead of `ImageView` in your `XML` layout. It has pinch to zoom in and out, as well as double tap to do the same too :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and what about the swiping functionality ??

Comment: swiping means that gallery like thing that `Whatsapp` has where you can slide through all photos in a chat at once?